# When #div toggled - get its height and move .divs

Tags: jquery, height, toggle

I have a toggle div (#toggle-div) and underneath I have some fixed positioned divs (.fixed-div). They need to be fixed due to some functionality on the page... Is there a way to – when the toggle button is pushed – get the height of #toggle-div and set the top-margin of the .fixed-div's the same amount of pixels? I found the following code:

```
var boxheight = ("#toggle-div").height();
$(".fixed-div").css({ margin-top: boxheight});
```

which to me seem to do what I want to achive, but it doesn't seem to work when added into the following toggle code... Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

This is my toggle code:

```
$("#toggle-hit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $("#toggle-div");
    $this.slideToggle("slow");
});
```

EDIT: Ok, so now I have partly found a solution.

```
$(".fixed-div").css("margin-top", 300);
```

Is working perfectly. But whenever I try to involve the height of the #toggle-div it fails;

```
var myBox = $('#toggle-div');
$('.fixed-div').css({margin-top: myBox.outerHeight()});
```

Is it because of the fact that it's a slideToggle? Can't understand why it isn't working. Is there maybe someone out there who know why it's doing like this?

EDIT 2: Okey, so I've sort of got it to work, by waiting for the toggle to finish and then get the height of the #toggle-div, and then do a little animation on the .fixed-div so it's not just jumping down.

```
var timing = setTimeout(function () {setHeight()}, 605);
function setHeight() {
    var boxes = $("#toggle-div").outerHeight() * 0.5;
$(".fixed-div").animate({
    marginTop: boxes + "px"}, 1000 );
};
```

So far so good. But when I hit the toggle button to close the #toggle-div, it actually adds more margin-top. I don't understand why is this, 'cause the height of the #toggle-div should be 0. Does anyone have a suggestion on this??

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, it should add or remove the top margin from `.fixed-div`, depending on the visibility state of `#toggle-div`:

```
$toggleHit = $('#toggle-hit');
$toggleElm = $('#toggle-div');
$fixedElm = $('.fixed-div');

$toggleHit.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $toggleElm.slideToggle('slow', function () {
        var isVisible = $toggleElm.is(':visible');
        var marginTop = isVisible ? $toggleElm.outerHeight() : 0;
        $fixedElm.css('margin-top', marginTop);
    });

});
```

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Now not even the toggle work. I've added an answer with my code right now, so if you want you can have a look and see if it's something that i've done wrong! Thanks in advance!